# LinkedIn Profile Builder not displaying anything?

Tags: javascript, html, linkedin-api

I am trying to use the [LinkedIn Profile Builder](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile-plugin-generator) to display a small preview of a profile on my blog.

The code I am using is this (replacing XXXXXX with a REAL user id):

```
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/in/XXXXXX" data-format="inline"></script>
</html>
```

For some reason when I do this, nothing is displayed. I get no error message in the console just a blank white page. I currently have only the snipped above in a .HTML page and it still doesn't load.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script tags have to be in the body tags.

Comment: Was it not working in the HEAD tags?  That seems more appropriate.  Why did you snippet not have head/body anyway?